# Failed to load interface for ‘System’

Tags: haskell

Can't import System both with GHC or GHCi

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS and The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.0.2

Can someone help me?

Comment: `System` is not a module. You can think of it as sort of a namespace for other modules, such as `System.IO`.

Comment: So this [example](https://wiki.haskell.org/High-level_option_handling_with_GetOpt#Advertised_technique) isn't correct

Comment: @AilsonForte Right, it's outdated

Comment: There's an example of how to use `System.Console.GetOpt` here: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/System-Console-GetOpt.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [example linked in the comments](https://wiki.haskell.org/High-level_option_handling_with_GetOpt#Advertised_technique) appears to work fine on modern GHC versions if you change the list of imports to:

```
import System.Console.GetOpt
import Control.Monad
import System.IO
import System.Exit
import System.Environment
```